# Write a query with Entity Framework in a booking app to search for available rooms

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I'm working on a booking application, and I'm having trouble writing a proper query when trying to fetch available rooms. The idea is simple, client chooses start and end date, number of occupants and the app gives him available rooms. This means that even if a room is currently booked, as long as the current reservation doesn't last until the start date of the client's reservation, it shows up as an option. However, I believe the code I wrote only checks the rooms which have had any kind of reservation related to them in the database, while it obviously should check them all. These are the tables

**Rooms**

```
int RoomId
int AccommodationId
```

**Rooms_Reservations**

```
int Rooms_ReservationsId
int RoomId
int ReservationId
```

**Reservations**

```
int ReservationId
int ReservationStatusId
DateTime DateFrom
DateTime DateTo
```

**ReservationStatus**

```
int ReservationStatusId
string ReservationStatusName
```

(basically Status = 2 means it's an active reservation, so if a pending or cancelled reservation 
covers the date range it still shows up as an option)

I skipped the other fields and only mentioned the ones relevant to this question. I tried using the accepted question related to room bookings, but I still got the same results, so please don't link me to the other asked question. This is my current one (if there's some basic intellisense errors it's cause I'm translating the code)

```
var list = (from room in _context.Rooms.Where(x => x.AccommodationId == search.AccommodationId)
            join rooms_reservations in _context.Rooms_Reservations
                 on room.RoomId equals rooms_reservations.RoomId
            join reservation in _context.Rezervacija
                 on rooms_reservations.ReservationId equals reservation.ReservationId
            join ReservationStatus in _context.ReservationStatus
                 on reservation.ReservationStatusId equals ReservationStatus.ReservationStatusId
            where ((reservation.DateFrom >= search.DateTo) || 
                   (reservation.DateTo <= search.DateFrom)) && 
                   ReservationStatus.ReservationStatusId != 2
            select new RoomModel()
                       {
                           // code to add inside the model
                       }).ToList();
```

This definitely doesn't work, since I don't have a single reservation in my database so far, yet when this query yields 0 results when I search, although it should list all the rooms from the accommodation. So in conclusion, this needs to show me any available room, even those who were never reserved before, and I believe that because I use "join reservation" that it only includes the rooms who show up in Rooms_Reservations records.

Comment: Set up relationships so you can use navigation-properties. You shouldn’t need to use explicit joins in your query.

Comment: Can you elaborate further with some code please?